# outlook contacts to sql server

Tags: sql-server, outlook

Is there any way to export outlook contacts directly into a sql server db ?  
This could be using a tool or programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would export from Outlook to Access using the Export command in Outlook, and then I would transfer to SQL Server using the Import and Export Data tool of SQL Server.

Comment: any more details on how you export to access?

Comment: i figured it out using the new upsizing wizard

Answer (score 2):

This link http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=25 show how to programatically synchronize outlook items with DB using LINK and ADO.NET.